# Having trouble associating additional view controllers to custom cocoa touch classes in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm a new user to SO and iOS programming.

When I'm in the Xcode 6 IDE and I create a new view controller and a new cocoa touch class, I'm having trouble associating the new view controller and the new custom class. As such, I cannot control-drag objects from the any view controller to the new .h or .m files.

I know that in Xcode 5 you were able to associate a view controller and a custom class through the identity inspector which I also see here, but I'm not able to add a new class, restart Xcode, and see new classes I make in this custom class dropdown as I saw people suggest for earlier versions of Xcode.

Also I should note that when I create new cocoa classes I intend to associate to view controllers, I'm inheriting from UIViewController as I saw suggested on another post about this topic but I am still not having success.

New class .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create your new class as a subclass of UIViewController, as you have already done.  Make sure you are creating a **Cocoa Touch** class here.

In Storyboard editor, select your view controller (the first of the three icons), switch to the Identity Inspector and use the dropdown (or just type the name of your new class if it won't autocomplete) into the **Class** field.

To create outlets and actions in your subclass, switch to assistant mode, and keep storyboard editor on the left, and open your new viewcontroller's .m file on the right.  Control drag from the UI element you want to create an action or outlet for, into the @implementation section, and release.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I was doing was clicking on the view controller in the storyboard and not the view controller button at the top of it. Once I clicked on that button at the top next to the first responder and exit, I was able to select the custom class from the drop-down. So embarrassing...